# Python best way to handle configs

Tags: python

*What is the Python best practice for managing config files and being able to overwrite any of configs before runnign wheel file?*

In our project we have about hunbred of paths (like `folder1/folder2/filename.csv`) configurations stored in the following way:

```
class PathsConfig(object):

  SOME_PATH = os.environ.get('SOME_PATH', 'folder1/folder2/filename.csv')  
  ...
```

The motivation for this approach (env variables) was ability to overwrite any of this paths before launching wheel file (important for QA team).

Recently I had a debate with my collegues about whether this approach implements [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config). As for me it isn't, because this paths are common for all environments (dev, qa, prod) and aren't sensitive. As for me those paths should be stored in config/yml files. *Am I right?*

P.S. I've found [opset](https://pypi.org/project/opset/) lib, but it doesn't look to be very popular, having only 5 start on GitHub.

Comment: It seems your question boils down to "should configuration be in the environment or yaml/json/...", is that correct? Are these settings deployment-specific, i.e. do they just *happen* to be the same for now or are they *always* the same (e.g. because the files are added as part of the installation)? Also, is this app used only by "you" (developers, company, ...) or "others" (users, customers, ...)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi better "should environment-agnostic configs be in the yaml/json? If yes - which lib to use and how to overwrite them for wheel file?"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi those paths are always the same, except QA team would like to overwrite them in Python notebooks

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this app is used only by company (developers, QAs)

Comment: So your argument is that these settings *aren't* configuration, since they don't need to be changed (except when they do), and thus don't need to be handled via environment variables? But then the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config) considers yaml a (weak) alternative *to environment variables*, whereas non-configuration should be stored as code - which is exactly what your snipped is doing already. So the code seems to already follow the suggestion: non-configuration (defaults) stored in code, configuration (overwrites) stored in environment variables.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi after Java world using environment variables for overwritting some path is something strange for me. For example, you can use Typesafe & .yml and overwrite single property https://blog.codacy.com/12-factor-config-for-java/. In my head, environment variables are for sensitive information, whether everything else is more cleaner to store in .yml (being able to overwrite). But I may be wrong of course